# Connect values of two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays

```
<?php
$array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
$array2 = array(0 => 'zero_b', 2 => 'two_b', 3 => 'three_b');
?>
```

i want the output to be:
    "zero: zero_a zero_b.
     one: one_a one_b.
     etc...

so i want the values of the two arrays connected by their appearance in the arrays.
I already tried it with foreach but it connected every value of one array with every value of the other array, so i ended up with 9 ouputs...

Comment: Could you clarify your question, it's hard to tell what your doing, what your trying to get and how your trying to get it

Comment: off the top of my head, array_merge_recursive. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: Please show code of what you're doing so people can better understand how to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
$array2 = array(0 => 'zero_b', 2 => 'two_b', 3 => 'three_b');
foreach(array_combine($array1,$array2) as $key=>$value) {

    echo substr($key,0,-2).":".$key." ".$value.".";

    //or
    //$k = explode("_",$key);
    //echo $k[0].":".$key." ".$value.".";

}
?>
```

Also it can be done for more than two arrays

```
<?php
$array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
$array2 = array(0 => 'zero_b', 2 => 'two_b', 3 => 'three_b');
$array3 = array(0 => 'zero_c', 2 => 'two_c', 3 => 'three_c');
//........more array
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value) {  
    $k = explode("_",$value);
    echo $k[0].":".$array1[$key]." ".
                   $array2[$key]." ".
                   $array3[$key].". "
                   //.........more array item concat
                   ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes it can be done for more than two arrays. Answe is updated look it.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly long winded, but works.

```
<?php
$array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
$array2 = array(0 => 'zero_b', 2 => 'two_b', 3 => 'three_b');
?>

<?php
$shortestArray = (count($array1) < $array2)? $array1 : $array2; // Get the max number of elements
$newArray = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($shortestArray); $i++){
    if(isset($array1[$i]) && isset($array2[$i])){
        array_push($newArray, $array1[$i]." ".$array2[$i]);
    }
}
$longestArray = ($shortestArray != $array1)? $array2 : $array1;
for($i = count($shortestArray)-1; $i < count($longestArray); $i++){
    array_push($newArray, $longestArray[$i]);
}

print_r($newArray);

?>
```